# Show that V is a vector space over the set of real numbers when V is the set of all real 3x3 matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces

Wondering how one would go on about this.

V is the set of all real 3 × 3 matrices.

How can it be shown that V is a vector space over the set of real numbers
and what would be the dimension of and basis for V? What would it be if it where the set of all anti-symmetric 3x3 matrices?

Comment: Well, first you need to determine how the addition and scalar multiplication is defined. Then you really just need to check the definition.

Comment: Could you show that $\Bbb R^3$ with the usual definitions of addition and scalar multiplication is a vector space over $\Bbb R$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are lots of ways to do this and, depending on what you're looking to get out of the exercise, the following may or may not be useful.

Note that $\Bbb R^9$ is a vector-space of dimension $9$ with basis consisting of the columns of $I_9$.

Now, define a bijective map $\Phi:\Bbb R^9\to M_{3\times 3}$ by 
$$
\Phi(\vec x)=
\begin{bmatrix}
x_1&x_2&x_3\\ x_4&x_5&x_6\\x_7&x_8&x_9
\end{bmatrix}
$$
We can use this map to *define* addition in and scalar multiplication on $M_{3\times 3}$ as follows. For $\Phi(\vec x),\Phi(\vec y)\in M_{3\times 3}$ define $\Phi(\vec x)+\Phi(\vec y)$ as $\Phi(\vec x+\vec y)$. For $\Phi(\vec x)\in M_{3\times 3}$ and $\lambda\in\Bbb R$ define $\lambda\cdot \Phi(\vec x)$ as $\Phi(\lambda\cdot x)$.

The map $\Phi$ transfers the linear structure of $\Bbb R^9$ onto $M_{3\times 3}$.

Comment: This is slightly silly, as it would work with any set of the correct cardinality (and would give vector spaces of any dimension).

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft Not that silly though, as different maps would give addition and scalar multiplication that aren't familiar. The point is we can do all the work in $\Bbb R^n$ and sensibly transfer the linear structure to the set in question.

Comment: Yes, but that is clearly not the point of the exercise, since the OP has probably had the structure defined previously.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft I make it pretty clear in my answer that this may or may not be of use from a "do your homework" perspective. The content here is correct and, in my opinion, quite useful even if OP's motivation is elsewhere.

Comment: Is the bijective map like a matrix? So why do we have 9 dimensions, cause the "matrix" has 3 columns/vectors and every column/vector has 3 elements/dimensions. Isn't the dimension the number of elements in a vector/column, so the bijective map displayed above shows us 9 different vectors?

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Check the definitions directly. Note that since these are 3x3 matrixes, there are 9 elements and hence youshould be working in a vector space of dimension 9.

How many dimensions are ther when they are anti-symmetric? Use the relationships provided by anti-symmetry to check the definitions. Do they still check out?